# Signalr Send message to specific client and group of client

Tags: signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client, signalr-backplane, signalr-2

I want to use signalr to send a message to specific user or group of users. Before that I want to map a user to connection ID. I am using deviceUUId for user login. I am unable to pass the deviceUUID in GetuserID method. I am getting deviceUUID from client side and hitting the api. Can I use the same deviceUUID  in MyOwnIdProvider? How can I map to a user?

```
//MyOwnIdProvider///

  public class MyOwnIdProvider:IUserIdProvider
{
    userDetial dbContext = new userDetial ();
  public string GetUserId(IRequest request)
  {
    if (request == null)
     throw new ArgumentNullException("request");
     if (request.User != null && request.User.Identity != null)
        {    
        var userId = LogInController.GetLoginDetails(userGUID.UserDeviceId);
         return userId.ToString();

        }
           // return request.User.Identity.Name;
        else
            return (string)null;
    }
}

 ///API controller///
 public class LogInController : ApiController
{
    [System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
    public int GetLoginDetails(userModel UserDeviceId)
    {
        var LogindeviceID = db.loginDetails(UserDeviceId.DeviceUUID);
        return LogindeviceID;
    }

}
```